# Is it possible with spacy rule-based matching to match two key words with up to a certain number of wildcards in-between?

Tags: nlp, pattern-matching, spacy

I am trying to match, for example, two keywords with up to five wildcards in-between. I could add five pattern with different numbers of wildcards, but this is not a good solution. Is there an option like `{"OP": "+5"}` or another solution?

Example:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a really nice, green apple. One apple a day ...!")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'ORTH': 'is'}, {"OP": "+"}, {"ORTH": "apple"} ]
matcher.add('test', None, pattern)
spans = [doc[start:end] for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc)]
for span in spans:
    print(spans)
```

This gives two matches:

`is a really nice, green apple` and `is a really nice, green apple. One apple`

But I want the first one only. It should work in general, thus splitting sentences etc. is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a really nice, green apple. One apple a day ...!")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{'ORTH': 'is'}]
for i in range(0,5):
    pattern.append({"OP": "?"}) 
pattern.append({"ORTH": "apple"})

matcher.add('test', None, pattern)
spans = [doc[start:end] for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc)]
for span in spans:
    print(spans)

# [is a really nice, green apple]
```